# exists function doesn't work as expected with dplyr transmute

Tags: r

I would like to do create the output as for df3 with dplyr transmute. But somehow it just takes the first row of the dataframe columns a and b and not the column itselft. any ideas?

```
df = data.frame(a=1:10, b=2:11)

df2 <- df %>%
  transmute(
    newcol = ifelse(exists("a", df)==TRUE,a, NA),
    newcol2 = ifelse(exists("b", df)==TRUE,b, NA),
    newcol3 = ifelse(exists("c", df)==TRUE,c, NA),
  )
df2


df3 = data.frame(newcol=1:10, newcol2=2:11, newcol3 = NA)
df3
```

Comment: Not quite clear. Are you looking for something like `df[setdiff(c('a', 'b', 'c'), names(df))] <- NA`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `exists("a", df)` returns a length-1 logical vector, so the `ifelse` returns a length-1 numeric vector. This is then recycled, which is why the first number in each column get recycled. You can use `if(condition) a else NA` instead:

```r
df = data.frame(a=1:10, b=2:11)

df2 <- df %>%
  transmute(
    newcol  = if(exists("a", df)) a else NA,
    newcol2 = if(exists("b", df)) b else NA,
    newcol3 = if(exists("c", df)) c else NA)
  )
df2
#>    newcol newcol2 newcol3
#> 1       1       2      NA
#> 2       2       3      NA
#> 3       3       4      NA
#> 4       4       5      NA
#> 5       5       6      NA
#> 6       6       7      NA
#> 7       7       8      NA
#> 8       8       9      NA
#> 9       9      10      NA
#> 10     10      11      NA
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map_dfc(c('a', 'b', 'c'),
      ~ if(exists(.x, df)) df %>% select(.x) else df %>% transmute(!! .x := NA))
```